# Shorten AWT exception stack trace

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt

When a AWT/swing application encounters an exception a very long stack trace is printed with lots of unnecessary information. Is there a way to only print the part that is relevant to my code and not everything which has to do with the swing/awt part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you are catching the `Exceptions` (which you should be), rather than directly calling `printStackTrace()` you could manually print (or exclude) each element by getting the StackTraceElements from `Throwable.getStackTrace()`
2. If you are using a logging library, you can change the output by changing the output of the library. For example, here's an example with [log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263741/log4j-formatting-is-it-possible-to-truncate-stacktraces) that changes the output
3. You can fiddle with the [-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865307/how-to-expand-size-of-java-stack-trace-to-see-bottom-of-stack-triggering-a-sta) JVM option