# maxjavastacktracedepth=-1 failed to create JVM

Tags: android

Full error:

```
MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 is outside allowed range [0 .... 1073741823],
improperly specified vm option 'MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1'

failed to create JVM. JVM path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

Last thing I did to break it:

Under Help → Edit Custom VM Options:

```
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx3072m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Android studio
- Deleting `vm` options.

```
-server
-Xms750m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-da
```

Comment: Can you post a little more to the problem you are having? E.g. what you're doing to cause the problem, what errors you get when you try to start.

Comment: What Java version are you using? This may happen if you're running on Java 5 or below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865307/how-to-expand-size-of-java-stack-trace-to-see-bottom-of-stack-triggering-a-sta#11872297. You could also try explicitly setting the JVM option to 0 to see how it reacts.

Comment: @i just deleted the vm options in the config files and it fixed :S i though the ones casuing the problem were in c:program files

Answer (score 6):

Delete the `vm` options in the `C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio3.4\config`.

Deleting the ones in the `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting vm options in the `C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio3.4\config\studio64.exe.vmoptions` does work.

Answer (score 5):

This is the path in my case.     `C:\Users\DELL\.AndroidStudio3.5\config\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

It may be different according to your android studio version.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Windows 10 and Android Studio 4.1, you should delete `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\studio64.exe.vmoptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this file :

```
C:\Users\{youy_user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3\studio64.exe.vmoptions
```